# HSD.test() grouping is defective

Tags: r, statistics, grouping, tukey

I am trying to compare the amount of soil Electrical Conductivity (EC) of seven different plant communities in a forest, so I have this data set and trying to compare the means using HDS.test(), the problem is it returns group "a" and "ab" but no group "b", my data is huge so not sure how to share it here, but here is my code:

```
EC_aov_result <- aov(EC ~ Veg, data = Veg)
HSD.test(EC_aov_result, trt = "Veg", group = T, console = T)
```

and here is the result:

```
$groups
          EC groups
5 -0.1774912      a
2 -0.1883102      a
1 -0.2101200      a
0 -0.2177784      a
6 -0.2251203     ab
7 -0.2790790     ab
3 -0.3100476     ab
4 -0.3330517     ab
```

as you see, there is no b, I haven't tried anything cause I couldn't find or come up with anything

Comment: You could share a sample like `dput(head(df,20))`?

Comment: Your model is overparameterised: it includes both an intercept (implicitly) and a factor.  Hence one level of the factor is aliased.  That may be the explanation.  Try `aov(EC ~ Veg - 1, data = Veg)`.  I suspect any "defect" is not with the function.  I cannot test my theory because your problem is not reproducible.